# Python Tornado updating shared data between requests

Tags: python, callback, tornado

I have a Python Tornado app. The app contains request handlers, for which I am passing data to like (the code below is not complete, and is just to illustrate what I want):

```
configs = {'some_data': 1, # etc.
          }

class Application(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [('/pageone', PageOneHandler, configs),
                    ('/pagetwo', PageTwoHandler, configs)]
        settings = dict(template_path='/templates',
                    static_path='/static', debug=False)
        tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers, **settings)

# Run the instance
# ... code goes here ...
application = Application()
http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
# ... other code (bind to port, etc.)

# Callback function to update configs
some_time_period = 1000 # Once an second
tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback(update_configs, some_time_period).start()
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

I want the `update_configs` function to update the `configs` variable defined above and have this change propagate through the handlers. For example (I know this doesn't work):

```
def update_configs():
    configs['some_data'] += 1

# Now, assuming PageOneHandler just prints out configs['some_data'], I'd expect
# the output to be: "1" on the first load, "2" if I load the page a second
# later, "4" if I load the page two seconds after that, etc.
```

The problem is, the `configs` variable is passed along to the handlers during creation in the constructor for the `Application` class. How can I update `configs['some_data']` in the periodic callback function?

My actual use case for this mechanism is to refresh the data stored in the `configs` dictionary from the database every so often.

Is there an easy way to do this without fiddling around with `application.handlers` (which I have tried for the past hour or so)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, the simplest thing would be to pass the entire config dict to the handlers, rather than just the individual values inside the dict. Because dicts are mutable, any change you make to the values in the dict would then propagate to all the handlers:

```
import tornado.web
import tornado.httpserver

configs = {'some_data': 1, # etc.
          }

def update_configs():
    print("updating")
    configs['some_data'] += 1

class PageOneHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def initialize(self, configs):
        self.configs = configs
    def get(self):
        self.write(str(self.configs) + "\n")


class PageTwoHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def initialize(self, configs):
        self.configs = configs

    def get(self):
        self.write(str(self.configs) + "\n")


class Application(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [('/pageone', PageOneHandler, {'configs' : configs}),
                ('/pagetwo', PageTwoHandler, {'configs': configs})]
        settings = dict(template_path='/templates',
                    static_path='/static', debug=False)
        tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers, **settings)

# Run the instance
application = Application()
http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
http_server.listen(8888)

# Callback function to update configs
some_time_period = 1000 # Once an second
tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback(update_configs, some_time_period).start()
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Output:

```
dan@dantop:~> curl localhost:8888/pageone
{'some_data': 2}
dan@dantop:~> curl localhost:8888/pageone
{'some_data': 3}
dan@dantop:~> curl localhost:8888/pagetwo
{'some_data': 4}
dan@dantop:~> curl localhost:8888/pageone
{'some_data': 4}
```

To me this approach makes the most sense; the data contained in `configs` doesn't really belong to any one instance of a `RequestHandler`, it's global state shared by all RequsetHandlers, as well as your `PeriodicCallback`. So I don't think it makes sense to try to create X numbers of copies of that state, and then try to keep all those different copies in sync manually. Instead, just share the state across your whole process using either a custom object with class variables, or a dict, as shown above.

Comment: Ah, you're totally right. I wasn't thinking about how the mutability of dictionaries can make this really simple. Thanks!

Comment: Is this still valid if the python process spawn other processes ? (Eg. if I start the `http_server` with `http_server.start(nproc)`,`http_server.bind(port)` and `IOLoop.start()`

Comment: Looks like no, so beware: it doesn't work if two or more processes are involved and you need (like me) to update & sync a state between handlers https://gist.github.com/giupo/f720f45748d5016eb440c1541b0535d1

Comment: @Giupo As you've discovered, no, this won't work with multiple processes. You'd need to use process-safe data structures, or a database, for that.

Comment: But I fount that use the DB is more secure to protect value.

Answer (score 6):

Another strategy, in addition to what dano mentions above is to attach the shared data to the Application object.

```
class MyApplication(tornado.web.Application):

    def __init__(self):

       self.shared_attribute = foo;

        handlers = [#your handlers here]        
        settings = dict(#your application settings here)
        super().__init__(handlers, **settings)


server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(MyApplication())
server.listen(8888)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Next you can access `shared_attribute` defined above in all your `request handlers` using `self.application.shared_attribute`.

You update it at one place and it immediately reflects in all your subsequent calls to the request handlers.