# How can I share variables between 2 classes when only 1 of them is instantiated?

Tags: python, tornado

So I have 2 python files, main.py which is the main file and web.py which contains the web app code (using Tornado). So in web.py, I want to share variables between the main web app class (WebAppModule, which is instantiated in main.py) and another class (WSHandler, which handles WebSocket connection from client-side). However, the only way I could think of is using a global variable (as demonstrated below via **is_button_clicked** variable). Is there any other way to do this?

**main.py**:

```
from web import WebAppModule

web_client = WebAppModule(9000)
```

**web.py**:

```
clients = []
wsThread = None
is_button_clicked = None

class WebAppModule():
    def __init__(self,portnumber):
        global is_button_clicked
        is_button_clicked = False
        self.process_running = ""
        self.connection_open = False

    def some_other_function:
        pass


class MyStaticFileHandler(tornado.web.StaticFileHandler):
    def set_extra_headers(self, path):
        self.set_header('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0')


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render('web/index.html')


class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        if len(clients)==0:
            clients.append(self)
            print 'web app connection opened...'
        else:
            print 'Another client already accessed the UI. Connection blocked...'

    def check_origin(self, origin):
        return True

    def on_message(self, message):
        for client in clients:    
            if "BUTTON_CLICKED" in message:
                global is_button_clicked
                is_button_clicked = True

    def on_close(self):
        try:
            clients.remove(self)
            print 'connection closed...'
        except Exception, e:
            print "Client not established. Skipped..."


settings = {
    "static_path": os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "web"),
    "static_hash_cache": False,
}    

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/ws', WSHandler),
    (r'/', MainHandler),
], static_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "web"), static_handler_class=MyStaticFileHandler)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Tornado updating shared data between requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25067916/python-tornado-updating-shared-data-between-requests)

Comment: I'm not familiar with Tornado, but in general is_button_clicked should be a property (or just a member variable) on a button object, or the object that 'owns' the button. Any object that needs to know if the button has been clicked can get passed a reference to that object, and access the property that way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a mutable object.  Strings are not mutable.  The reason is that python evaluates only once, so any mutable string that is changed, is changed for the whole app during the run.

```
shared = {'wsThread':None,
          'is_button_clicked':None
         }
```

Then update in a def like:

```
def set(self, value):
    shared['is_button_clicked'] = value

def get(self):
    return shared['is_button_clicked']
```